# How to bind rows resulting from different MySQL queries?

Tags: sql, mysql

I´d like to add several rows stemming from another SQL query (different table) to a query result. e.g.:

```
SELECT mycol from mytable 

# returns 
mycol
1
4
6
SELECT anothercol from anothertable
#returns
anothercol
3
8
9
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
myresult
1
4
6
3
8
9
```

Currently I do this kind of operation with statistical software packages, but I wonder if that is possible in MySQL somehow. It's often needed when merging time series from different sources. Is there a SQL way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Merge 2 tables for a SELECT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129659/mysql-merge-2-tables-for-a-select-query)

Comment: Per below, to combine result sets of two separate queries, you use a UNION. Check the MySQL reference manual (online and very human readable) for syntax and details. Use UNION ALL if you want to preserve values that appear in both result sets.

Answer (score 7):

Use the UNION statement.

It's something like:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 34)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 = 45);
```

Then you can add an ORDER BY at the end like:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 34)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 = 45)
ORDER BY column;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  mycol
FROM    mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT  othercol
FROM    othertable
```

Answer (score 1):

This question might be helpful: [Merge 2 tables for a SELECT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129659/mysql-merge-2-tables-for-a-select-query)