# Get Query for two table.

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I implemented my project in Yii. I wrote query for single table like query with condition.

I want to write query to call from the two different table. I've tables are recipe and ingredient table. Recipe table I've more than 7 fields. recipe_id, cuisinename, course_id, type etc. another table ingredient. id, ingredient_name.

```
$result="SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND `cuisinename` LIKE 
'$cuisine1%' AND course_id  LIKE '%$course1%' AND `type` LIKE '%$type1%' 
AND `calorie_count` LIKE '$calorie1%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC";
```

I wrote this condition. my search function is working very well. But I want to display from the other table i.e. ingredient table also.

could I write like query??

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129659/merge-2-tables-for-a-select-query (found by using Google).

Comment: i dont want join query. i want to write sql query to search and fetch the values from the two tables

Comment: see my answer below for an idea on how you can do it

Comment: if someone resolve you problem, mark his question as a decision

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `JOIN`. However I would imagine Recipe and Ingredients would have a many to many relationship in your database. You'd need to first make an `associative table` for them and then use an `INNER JOIN` to link up the 3 tables.

Something like this:

```
SELECT /* you stuff */
FROM recipe_ingredients ri
INNER JOIN recipe r ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ri.ingredient_id = i.id
WHERE /* do you like stuff here */
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, you could try this;

```
/* first query */
$query = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND `cuisinename` LIKE '$cuisine1%' AND course_id  LIKE '%$course1%' AND `type` LIKE '%$type1%' AND `calorie_count` LIKE '$calorie1%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$ret1 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

/* second query */
$query = "Whatever is in your second query?"; //add your second query here..
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$ret2 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

/*final result set */
$result = array_merge((array)$ret1, (array)$ret2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yii, use query builder http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Query will look like

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*, i.ingridient_name')
    ->from('recipe t')
    ->join('ingredients i', 'i.recipe_id=t.id')
    ->where('name LIKE :name AND `cuisinename` LIKE 
          :cuisine1 AND course_id  LIKE :course1 AND `type` LIKE :type1 
          AND `calorie_count` LIKE :calorie1', array(
          ':name'=>'%'.$name.'%',
          ':cuisine1'=>'%'.$cuisine1.'%',
    ))
    ->order('recipe_id DESC')
    ->queryAll();
```